# Do While Loop Code

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
        do{
        game1.getBetAmountFromUser();
        bet = game1.returnBetAmount();

        if (bet!=0){
            game1.playGame();
            pot = game1.returnPotAmount();
            System.out.println("");             
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You end the game with pot of $" + formatter.format(pot));
            bet = game1.returnBetAmount();
            }
        }while (pot != 0 && bet == 0);
```

I am very confused with what is happening in this code.

I am doing a do loop and asking to only loop when two criteria are met.  But when I set bet to 0, the loop continues.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if `bet` is 0, you never assign `pot = game1.returnPotAmount();`, so `pot` may remain 0 (if that is its initial value), which means the loop won't terminate.

Perhaps you intended your condition to be - `while (pot != 0 && bet != 0);`

Comment: I am an idiot.  This is what I get for doing coding at 4am.  I needed to have while(pot!=0 && bet != 0)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your loop termination code:

```
  ... } while (pot != 0 && bet == 0);
```

This says (in effect) "keep going while the pot is not zero and the bet is zero".  But you want to terminate (NOT keep going) when the bet is zero.  So your code should test for the bet being NOT zero ... in the "keep going".

The keyword `while` means roughly the same thing as the word "while" in English.